# Are singular matrices diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A_{n\times n}$ be Hermitian with eigenvalues $\lambda_1 > \lambda_2 > \ldots > \lambda_r=0$ and multiplicities $q_1,...,qr$. Can $A$ be diagonalized? Is the matrix of eigenvalues

$$L_{n\times n}=\text{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_{r-1},\lambda_r,\ldots,\lambda_r)$$

a similar matrix to $A$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every Hermitian matrix is diagonalizable by the [spectral theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Hermitian_matrices), with its eigenvalues along the diagonal, so the answer to both of your questions is `yes'.

Answer (score 1):

As you can argue by Spectral Theorem, hermitian matrices are always diagonalizable. Thus the diagonalized matrix has exactly eigenvalues along the diagonal.